# Exposing that your app is installed to the android browser

Tags: android

I am trying to find a way to detect in the android browser whether my application has been installed.

Use case:
I have a web page that a user can reach via their android web browser.  If the application is installed it would show "Tips & tricks".  If it is not installed, it would show promotional material and a link to download the app.

Attempted solution:
My initial thoughts have been to associate my application with a custom mime type using  the apps manifest and in the web page iterate javascript's mimeTypes array.  I figured if the mime type showed up in the array, I could assume that the application was installed.

Unfortunately, the mimeTypes array doesn't ever change.

Any ideas how I could determine if my application is installed when the user accesses my web page via the android browser?

Thanks for any help / insight you might have.

Comment: This is just a thought and something I haven't tested at all, but you might be able to access a gears db via both the device and the site.  Although that has the disadvantage that the user would have to enable gears for your site in the browser on the device.  Again not even sure if that is possible but might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your local application start a local http server. From your webpage you try to get some predefined resource from this local app. If it is installed it will serve and you know that your app is installed. If not your app is not installed on the host device.